# How to automatically overscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a kiosk webpage that will go on an Ipad. I have found an app that lets me go fullscreen but to go fullscreen you have to overscroll on the bottom. Is there a way to force my webpage to automatically do this?
I have tried using autoscroll with no luck. I don't care how it is done (CSS, HTML, Javascript, jQuery)

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: What do u mean by over scroll? as in going beyond the limit?

Comment: @Smit Yes, On mobile devices (at least apple) when you are on a web browser you can push the webpage up past the end of the page. I think it is called overscrolling if it is called something else please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use HTML5 fullscreen API:

```
var i = document.getElementById("myimage");

// go full-screen
if (i.requestFullscreen) {
    i.requestFullscreen();
} else if (i.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    i.webkitRequestFullscreen();
} else if (i.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    i.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (i.msRequestFullscreen) {
    i.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Detail:https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-full-screen-api/

Comment: I added this to my code but it had no effect. This should work for mobile right?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
<iframe style="width:100%;height:600px" src="websitehere"></iframe>
</div></div>
```

Comment: First off you need an extra close </div> but when I used your code it worked but I have to click "test 123" for it to work correctly. Is there a way for this to work automatically?

Comment: Do you insert iframe with webpage kiosk.